# Where to enable pending Pact in Open Source Pact Broker

Tags: java, testing, pact

We want to prevent our Pact Provider Tests to fail if the Consumer publishes a new/updated Pact.
For that I add in failsafe Plugin. We are using Maven and Java

```
<pactbroker.enablePending>true</pactbroker.enablePending>
<pactbroker.providerTags>main</pactbroker.providerTags>
</systemProperties>
```

But I am not sure if I also have to configure the Open Source Pact Broker.
In the pact I never see the pending flag set to true

If I have a pact which is green and I change it and publish it I would expect pendung to be true. That's my understanding

Answer (score 1):

Pending is not a status on a contract, it is dynamically calculated based on a number of factors. See https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/advanced_topics/pending_pacts.

You enable the setting on the provider wide to prevent your provider build breaking on new changes - this

See https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/workshops/ci-cd/ for a workshop that explains how it works

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let's say I only want to use the pending feature for the main branch or branches ending with -feature . How can I do that ? I know there are 2 system properties for the provider: pactbroker.providerTags and pactbroker.providerBranch For the consumer there is the system property: pact.consumer.tags Right now in my case just any available contract gets verified when pending is enabled

Comment: Pending applies to whatever contracts you have selected using consumer version selectors (see. docs.pact.io/selectors). You can't do branch regexes but you can programmatically specify the branch name)

Comment: ok. If I set System variable pactbroker.consumerversionselectors.rawjson={ "mainBranch": true } now the consumer has to publish its branch. How can I do this? -> I think I will need e.g. a Git plugin to get the branch name + I need to set some property in the pact maven plugin

Comment: I moved some microservices from pactbroker.providerTags to pactbroker.providerBranch but just 50% of all services so far. Is it bad if I haven't changed all microservices ?